# How to insert dot/period on the authors in bbl file using BST

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I need to insert end period after the every last author of the references:

My Bibfile:

```
@article{winograd1972understanding,
author={Winograd, Terry},
year={1972},
title={Understanding natural language},
journal={Cognitive Psychology},
volume={3},
number={1},
pages={1--191}
}
```

Wrong Output:

```
\bibtype{Article}%%
\bibitem[{Winograd}(1972)]{winograd1972understanding}
\bibinfo{author}{Winograd, Terry} \bibinfo{year}{1972}.
\bibinfo{title}{Understanding natural language}.
{\em \bibinfo{journal}{Cognitive Psychology}\/}
  \bibinfo{volume}{3}(\bibinfo{number}{1}):\bibinfo{pages}{1--191}.
```

Required Output:

```
\bibtype{Article}%%
\bibitem[{Winograd}(1972)]{winograd1972understanding}
\bibinfo{author}{Winograd, Terry}**.** \bibinfo{year}{1972}.
\bibinfo{title}{Understanding natural language}.
{\em \bibinfo{journal}{Cognitive Psychology}\/}
  \bibinfo{volume}{3}(\bibinfo{number}{1}):\bibinfo{pages}{1--191}.
```

My Bibfile:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
    duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { collaboration "collaboration" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { " (" swap$ * ")" * }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
    { add.period$ write$
      newline$
      "" write$
    }
    { output.state before.all =
        'write$
        { add.period$ " " * write$ }
      if$
    }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}

FUNCTION {book}
{ newline$
  "\bibtype{Book}%" write$
   output.bibitem
    format.opennote output
   author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
      add.blank
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.month output
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check emphasize
  format.edition "edition" output.check
  format.bknote "bknote" output.check
  format.titlecomment "titlecomment" output.check
  format.series "series" output.check
  format.volume "volume" output.check
  format.number "number" output.check
  format.publisher "publisher" output.check
  format.address "address" output.check
  new.block
%%  format.isbn output
%%  format.book.pages output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note empty$
  { }
  {format.note output.check }
  if$
  format.eprint output
  format.url output
  format.endnote output
  format.chapter output
  format.type output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
   "(" swap$ * ")" *
      *
    }
  if$
}
```

It would be appreciate if someone show the path to alter the `.bst` file.

Comment: Your example can't be used to test. So you can only get try and error answers. Maybe something like this `FUNCTION {book}
{ ....
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull`

Comment: I have edited my question and FYI this BST I have edited for someone request for outputs.